# Flutter & Firebase: How work email and password reset when account come from social authentification?

Tags: flutter, mobile, firebase-authentication

I'm building application with flutter and implement Authentication with Gmail and Facebook. I would like to understand how the password or email reset works for gmail or facebook accounts. For example I tried to change the email of a Gmail account and when I look in the firebase console I see this:[image]

The provider remains the same but the domain name is different. Want to understand Please.
And with password can i change password for social account? What will be behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change passwords for social authentications,
So Social Authentication concept is to verify you from your other social account. Think you are go to some security place policeman request your ID but you have no ID right now. But you have Driving License you can show it. Same thing here you don't need to create account you can your social account for authenticate it's you, your social account's password is not important for Firebase login but you need to in authentication time logged to your social account. you can change the password later it's not problem for your Firebase project.

I think your Problem is i'm covered

Comment: Thanks. But what about the password?